# SSRS Divide by Zero error on totals with weighted average

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

When attempting to get a total weighted average interest rate I occasionally receive Error when there is only one item in certain columns. Having trouble with the Iif statement handling this:

```
=Iif(Sum(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value) = 0, 0, SUM(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value * Fields!WAIR.Value))/Iif(Sum(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value) = 0, 1, SUM(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value))
```

Comment: Some sample data for which the error occurs would help

Answer (score 0):

Moved your brackets slightly, this seems to work:

```
=Iif(Sum(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value) = 0, 0, 
    SUM(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value * Fields!WAIR.Value)/Iif(Sum(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value) = 0, 1, SUM(Fields!Current_Principal_Balance.Value)))
```